# How to properly use VS auto closing brace feature?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and it automatically adds a closing brace when I type an opening brace. However, it can be quite annoying at times e.g.

```
if (bFlag)
    Console.Output("Hello World");
```

Now if I wanted to enclose Console.Output code in braces, and enter an opening brace after the if expression, VS automatically places a closing brace there as well e.g.

```
if (bFlag)
{}
    Console.Output("Hello World");
```

This is annoying in that first I have to delete the closing brace and then manually type in closing brace at the end. Is there an automagical way of doing this? I don't necessarily want to disable the auto-close brace feature.

Edit: I'm hoping for a more intelligent solution that automatically adds parenthesis at the end of the expected code block (read: it automatically detects code block). In the example I gave earlier, when I type opening brace after 'if' clause, it should automatically put a closing brace before the 'else' clause etc. If I have to first select all the code and then press a hot-key combo (typically twice), I might as well just manually put the opening/closing braces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to surround code block with Curly Braces {} in VS2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769508/any-way-to-surround-code-block-with-curly-braces-in-vs2008)

Comment: Cut before you do your open bracket and then paste

Comment: I also use vs tricks for free and there is a surround with hot key.