# Visual Studio - Is there a shortcut to insert parentheses around a selection?

Tags: visual-studio

I am playing with Atom and I really like how I can select an expression and press `Shift+9` to insert `(` and `)` outside it. This is convenient for Haskell and I would like the same for F#. Is there a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Released February 13th, 2024, [Visual Studio 2022 17.9 supports this feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/whats-new-for-cpp-developers-in-visual-studio-2022-17-9/?WT.mc_id=academic-0000-abartolo).

> Auto Surround with Quotes or Brackets You can now easily surround a
> selection with bracket delimiters including: “double quotes”, ‘single
> quotes’, and (parentheses). Just select an area of code and press the
> relevant key.
>
> To enable or disable this feature, go to Tools > Options > Text Editor
> and check the “Automatically surround selections when typing quotes or
> brackets” option.

Comment: `Asked 7 years, 9 months ago.` It really took a while for this feature to arrive, but I am glad it did.

Answer (score 27):

This is an in-built option in Visual Studio 2017. Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `C / C++` -> `Advanced`, then navigate within the options dialog as shown on the screenshot below.

Set the `Enable Surround with Parentheses` option to `True`.

This works for C++, but the process ought to be similar for other languages.

Once you click `OK`, you should be able to automatically insert parentheses around any selected text by typing only the first `(`

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Text Editor Options]

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think F# has that. I can't find the option.

Comment: It's also not available for C#. That's crazy.

Answer (score 9):

Stumbled upon this when searching parenthesis surrounding for C# in VS2022. Another free method (non-hacky) to add in Dan Cundy's list: [Auto Surround](https://github.com/reduckted/AutoSurround) extension available for Visual studio 2022

Answer (score 6):

### Paid Method

You should check out a third party add-in like Resharper. They bundle a such abilities.

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

### Free Method

There is another method noted by @Igor Zevaka.

Here: [Any way to surround code block with Curly Braces {} in VS2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2769697/2468342)

This allows you to create a snippet, and use a shortcut to use it.

> Here is a quick and dirty snippet to do just that.
>
> To Install:
>
> Save the code as SurroundWithBraces.snippet into "\Visual Studio Version\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code
> Snippets"
>
> To use:
>
> Select block of text. Press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S Chose My Code Snippets,
> braces
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
> <CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
>   <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
>     <Header>
>       <Title>braces</Title>
>       <Shortcut>braces</Shortcut>
>       <Description>Code snippet to surround a block of code with braces</Description>
>       <Author>Igor Zevaka</Author>
>       <SnippetTypes>
>         <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
>         <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
>       </SnippetTypes>
>     </Header>
>     <Snippet>
>       <Code Language="csharp">
>         <![CDATA[{
>         $selected$ $end$
>      }]]>
>       </Code>
>     </Snippet>
>   </CodeSnippet>
> </CodeSnippets>
> ```

Comment: Actually, I knew that Resharper has that based on [an article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/27/8-resharper-shortcuts-everyone-should-know/) that I read, but I thought that something like this might be possible without any expensive plugins. I am not doing dev in C# or any of the other VS languages apart from F#.

Comment: Did you see the post with the snippet? Seems like there isn't much around for this.

Comment: I tried something similar to the above before I saw your edit, and I could get the snippet to import in F#. There might be something wrong with the [F# code snippet](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d19080ad-d44c-46ae-b65c-55cede5f708b) plugin. Unlike C#, F# cannot use snippets without an extension. At any rate, I'll leave this for now. Since this is rather simple, it might be worth looking into how to write a `Shift+9` surround plugin specifically for this.

Comment: Downvoted for advertising an expensive, subscription-based 3rd party extension for a functionality that could be accomplished via a short snippet in Visual Studio.

Comment: @RobertSynoradzki I also provided a free method after though using the short snipper you mention, perhaps I need to make that clearer.